# assertionError in Lattice

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I've been struggling with Sphinx for a while now and all of the sudden I keep getting this  assertion error, which reads as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
at edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Lattice.<init>(Lattice.java:170)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult.<init>(SpeechResult.java:43)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.getResult(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:51)
at AudioRecognizer.getAudioFileResult(AudioRecognizer.java:38)
at AudioRecognizer.processAudioFile(AudioRecognizer.java:45)
at AudioRecognizer.main(AudioRecognizer.java:115)
```

The line in my code it's struggling with is

```
    SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
```

The line in Sphinx's source code it's struggling with is

```
    assert token != null && token.getWord().isSentenceEndWord();
```

It did not have a problem with this before. The only thing I changed was that I removed the language model and used a grammar (for which I added in `setGrammarPath(true)`, `setGrammarName()` and `setGrammarPath()` with appropriate arguments of course), and when I trace it through debug on Eclipse `token` doesn't seem to be `null`. The audio file it's looking at is literally just someone saying "span."

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? I'm at a complete loss as to why this is no longer working.

Comment: At current state of things lattices can not be constructed from the grammars, so its more a bug in sphinx4.

Comment: So does this mean that ultimately I can't get a SpeechResult if my program is using a grammar?

Comment: Maybe you can provide the data to reproduce your problem (audio file and grammar) and I can take a look what is going on there.